# In React, How do I redirect a user back to the index with altered state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, ecmascript-6

In my React.JS application, I want to create a link which does nothing more than alter the client's state, but show the main index page. For example, the main page is:

```
http://example.com/#/
```

This shows the main index page. Now, if a user is directed to this page:

```
http://example.com/#/check?arg=abcd
```

I would want to still show the user the main index page, but have the `this.props` variable be affected by the `arg=abcd`

I define my routes with:

```
var routes = (
    <Route handler={APP}>
        <DefaultRoute handler={Index} />
        <Route name="check" path="check" handler={check}></Route>
    </Route>
);
```

So I do have a route which takes in a `check` path, but again my goal is to just use the argument to `check` and still keep showing the regular index page.

What is the most efficient way of doing this with React.JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I could circumvent the need of a second page and router. All I need to do is use an argument handler on the index page. I am away from work and on mobile so I will answer my own question tomorrow when I get in.

Update -- 
So this is how I got it working:

I added a new line to the route set up:

```
var routes = (
    <Route handler={APP}>
        <DefaultRoute handler={Index} />
        <Route path="/arg1/:arg1" handler={Index} />
    </Route>
);
```

The line with arg1. Then I made sure the handler to that path was {Index}. Now, within my component, I have the following line:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this._handleArgs(this.props.params.arg1);
},
```

Which will handle (or not-handle if arg1 is null) any args before mounting the component.

So, no need to add a new component, just another route to the same component and some helper functions.